# Redis Server is down twice a day why?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I install Redis Server in Ec2 instance and type is STANDALONE. Storage of my redis is more than 6Million Keys.After crossing this storage server is down frequently twice a day why how to overcome this Issue ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Any reason not to use the managed redis instances available through ElastiCache? 
 https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/ Otherwise, you would need to provide a lot more detail to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Is the Ram size issue ?
My instance has 4gb ram currently storage is 3.33GB this may cause issue?

Comment: Check the server logs for the process, especially around the time it’s not available. Nobody can say why it doesn’t work with the info provided without guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's quite possible that you are running out of memory and the OOM is killing the process.

Try setting the memory limit

```
config set maxmemory <80% of your instance memory size>
```

and check your [eviction policy](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/administering/database-operations/eviction-policy/) so you know how to handle memory being full

Comment: However likely this is the answer, it is always best to find the reason _first_

Comment: Automatically, when the memory is full  is it possible to delete the old key not the latest keys ?

Comment: I recommend setting a TTL on the keys if you can.  As that is not always possible changing the eviction policy to  allkeys-lru it will start removing the least recently used key when memory pressure starts.  Be aware that this may remove keys you want.

Comment: I set the policy and max memory now its working

Comment: After reach its memory limit is Redis performance will low?

What are all the steps should i want to follow for performance tuning in Redis?

Comment: Before attempting to tune performance, it's often best to collect redis statistics using Prometheus etc before attempting to start twisting performance configs

Comment: Thanks will collect the statistics

Comment: Right now i am using redis insight to see the data 
Is that best to collect statistics or else we need use prometheus?
@namizaru

Comment: Redis Insight is amazing for real-time and offers very good tuning suggestions.

Comment: Could you please suggest the config for performance tuning?

Comment: The configuration is going to rely heavily on what your server is doing.  There's not silver bullet here